# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/semanticweb/owlapi/model/OWLOntologyCreationException

Tags: owl-api

Help please !

The project works in eclipse but when I switch on the command line (to launch several examples) I obtien this exception

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/semanticweb/owlapi/model/OWLOntologyCreationException
    at com.lc.pilot.test.Main.main(Main.java:34)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLOntologyCreationException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 1 more

Answer (score 0):

What is the classpath set when you run your code from the command line?
The error means you're missing the jar containing the declaration for `OWLOntologyCreationException` - this is either the `owlapi-api` jar or the `owlapi-distribution` jar, depending on how you set up your Eclipse project.